# Graphviz: Connecting Nodes

Tags: python-3.x, graphviz, diagram

I am a trial and error analyst, trying to make flow charts for processes that I have created. I am coding in python (3.8) and have brought in the library **diagrams**. The creation of my flowchart has been wrought with confusion as to how variables are to be defined to illicit the desired layout. I have been able to make some variable definitions work as desired (i.e., *Node('test', shape='cds')*), however, most other variable definition attempts to (i.e.,) get node connections to go from **head node center right** to **tail node center left** have been in vain.

1. I know my use of the **diagrams** library has been bastardized while trying to make the underlying **graphviz** work for my context.
2. I have had little success trying to use dictionaries as input in graph_attr
3. How can I start being able to use the variables for nodes, edges, and clusters to utilize the options I am seeing in https://graphviz.gitlab.io/docs/nodes/ and https://gitlab.com/search?group_id=1996273&project_id=4207231&repository_ref=main&scope=blobs&search=%22headport%22

"""

```
node_shp1 = 'cds'
with Diagram('Variable Usage', show=False):
    edge_blk = Edge(headport="c", tailport="c", color="black")

    with Cluster('Primary Cluster'):

        with Cluster('Cluster1'):
            c = Node('C\n\n')
            d = Node('D\n\n\n\n')
            e = Node('E\n\n\n')
            f = Node('F\n\n\n')
            g = Node('G\n\n\n')
            h = Node('H\n\n\n')
            source = [d, e, f, g, h]

        i = Node('I\n\n\n', shape=node_shp1)
        with Cluster('Cluster2'):

            j = Node('J\n\n\n\n')
            k = Node('K\n\n\n')
            l = Node('L\n\n\n')
            m = Node('M\n\n\n')
            n = Node('N\n\n\n')
            test = [j, k, l, m, n]

        o = Node('O\n\n\n', shape=node_shp1)
        c >> edge_blk >> o >> i >> test
```

[image: result]